# QGis: how to reload plug-ins?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am developing a set of plug-ins for QGis (2.14). Every time I need to try it out I must quit and relaunch QGis. Is there any way to force QGis to reload the plug-ins without restarting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `Plugin Reloader` plugin - it's experimental but works very well.

Experimental plug-ins must be activated

Comment: I can not find that one in the list.

Comment: Make sure you have enough experiments turned on

Comment: Nice. Can you please add to your answer that Experimental plug-ins must be activated?